# PHP image upload code working on localhost but not working on server

Tags: php, image-upload

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","namkaran");
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into upload_data (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`)
    VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    $desired_dir="user_data";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700); // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{              // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Photos Uploaded Succesfully !!";
}
 }
 ?>
```

This is my image upload code, it works superb on localhost but not working when uploaded on server.
        The code saves the uploaded images into a folder called user_data which the code creates itself if it doesn't exist. And than saves the images in the folder. On localhost it created a folder itself started saving images into the folder but online its not creating the folder, when i manually created the folder its still not saving the images in the folder. The code isn't giving any errors msgs instead gives me the success msg.

Comment: my html : <tr><td> Upload Pics : </td>
  <td>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/></td>

</td></tr>

Comment: Can you please list errors/warnings ?

Comment: do you have write permission on your server?

Comment: Are you passing the correct mysql authentication parameters?

Comment: Do you have permission to log into `root` in the MySQL server?

Comment: Hey i m new to php.. how do i find all these permissions are there are not ?

Comment: MySQL_Query will not work with MySQLi_connect()

Comment: Mostly a permission issue, you should be able to check the directory permissions using fileperms, more informations here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php. If you see that you don't have writing rights, edit them via chmod (PHP command / Server explorer GUI ...)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your database connection succeeds and all queries are
   correct
2. Make sure your script has write permissions on the server
3. If it doesn't help, try debugging your code to find out where it goes wrong